# Comparing two string columns having values as "PO","GO" etc of a dataframe and creating a third column having values as "High","Low" and "No Change"

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I have two columns in a dataframe. Column one is named as previous_code and column two is named as New_code.These columns have values as "PO","GO","RO" etc. These codes have priority for example "PO" has higher Priority compared to "GO".I want to compare values of these two columns and Put the output in new column as "High","Low" and "No Change" incase both the columns have same code. Below is the example of how dataframe looks like

```
CustID|previous_code|New_code
345.    | PO.                   | GO
367.    | RO.                   | PO
385.    |PO.                    | RO
455.    |GO.                    |GO
```

Expected output Dataframe

```
CustID|previous_code|New_code|Change

345.    | PO.                   | GO.            | Low
367.    | RO.                   | PO.            |High
385.    |PO.                    | RO.            |Low
455.    |GO.                    |GO.             |No Change
```

If someone could write a demo code for this in pyspark or Pandasthat will be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you share some data or a minimum reproducible example? What do you mean with " I am unable to write a code for this in pyspark or pandas"? If you want "demo code" check the documentation for `numpy.select` or `numpy.where`

Comment: @Celius Stinger,  have added some dummy data for more clarity. I could not post actual Dataframe. Actually I have tried to write a code but I wasn't able to get the desired output. I don't have code snippet with me right now.

Comment: Ah ok thanks. I thought we could **not** use pandas.

Comment: The order is PO > GO > RO right?

Comment: @Celius,  yes that's correct.

Comment: @Steven Could you please remove downvote as I have already tried to solve this issue and was unable to do that and asked this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the ordering correctly, this should work fine:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = {'CustID':[345,367,385,455],'previous_code':['PO','RO','PO','GO'],'New_code':['GO','PO','RO','GO']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
mapping = {'PO':1,'GO':2,'RO':3}
df['previous_aux'] = df['previous_code'].map(mapping)
df['new_aux'] = df['New_code'].map(mapping)
df['output'] = np.where(df['previous_aux'] == df['new_aux'],'No change',np.where(df['previous_aux'] > df['new_aux'],'High','Low'))
df = df[['CustID','previous_code','New_code','output']]
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   CustID previous_code New_code     output
0     345            PO       GO        Low
1     367            RO       PO       High
2     385            PO       RO        Low
3     455            GO       GO  No change
```